# RSelenium - how to go to the next page by cliking on the button next?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

my question is about scraping with RSelenium.

I am trying to scrape data from the following website:

"https://www.nhtsa.gov/ratings" using RSelenium.

My present difficulty lies in managing to skip between pages for a given carmaker.

This is my code so far:

```
library(RSelenium)

#opens a connection
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD$client

#goes to the page we want
url <- "https://www.nhtsa.gov/ratings"
remDr$navigate(url)

#clicking to open the manufacturer selection "page"
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#vehicle a")
webElem$clickElement()

#opening the options menu
option.menu <- remDr$findElement(using='css selector', 'select')
option.menu$clickElement()

#selecting one maker, loop over this later
maker.select <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = 'AUDI']")
maker.select$clickElement()

#search our selection
maker.click<-remDr$findElement(using='css selector', '.manufacturer-search-submit')
maker.click$clickElement()

#now we have to go through each car (10 per page), loop later
cars<-remDr$findElement(using='css selector', 'tbody:nth-child(6) a')
individual.link<-cars$getElementAttribute("href")

#going to the next page
next_page<-remDr$findElement(using='css selector', 'button.btn.link-arrow::after')
next_page$clickElement()
```

But I get the error:

```
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

As you can probabily see I am new to RSelenium. Any help that you can give me would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that might be of help.

You can access the data simply by sending a `GET` request to the website. From the website (on the first page), we can see

```
'https://api.nhtsa.gov/vehicles/byManufacturer?offset=0&max=10&sort=overallRating&order=desc&data=crashtestratings,recommendedfeatures&productDetail=all&dateStart=2011-01-01&manufacturerName=AUDI&dateEnd=3000-01-01&name='
```

This is where we can get the data. The second page will have `offset=10` then `20,30,etc`.

If `api_url` is defined to be the above url, then we can get the data using `httr`

```
# request the data
request <- httr::GET(api_url)
# retrieve the content
request_content <- httr::content(request)
request_result <- request_content$results
# request results contains the data of interest
# A few glimpses into the data
# The first model
request_result[[1]]$vehicleModel
# [1] "A3"
request_result[[1]]$modelYear
# [1] 2018
request_result[[1]]$manufacturer
# [1] "AUDI OF AMERICA, INC"
```

Now by playing around with `offset` it is straight forward to build a loop and gather all pages

```
out <- list()
k <- 0L
i <- 1L
while (k < 1e+3) {
  req_url <- paste0('https://api.nhtsa.gov/vehicles/byManufacturer?offset=',
                    k, 
                    '&max=10&sort=overallRating&order=desc&data=crashtestratings,recommendedfeatures&productDetail=all&dateStart=2011-01-01&manufacturerName=AUDI&dateEnd=3000-01-01&name=')
  req <- httr::content(httr::GET(req_url))$result
  if (length(req) == 0) break
  out[[i]] <- req
  cat(paste0('\nAdded content for offset \t', k))
  i <- i + 1L
  k <- k + 10L
}
lengths(out)
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Note that you can also play around with `manufacturerName` in the url and with many more arguments to have clean and tailored data.